# How to place widgets above and relative to an image in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently working on an app for students, which describes various practical experiments.
The app consists of several AccordionItems.
The problem arises with one of them, where I want to embed an image, which keeps its aspect ratio but adapts to be as big as possible. To explain parts of the image, I would like to put semi-transparent buttons on interesting devices/objects that provide information in text form at on_release.

By stretching the app window in x or y direction and the fact that stretching the image is not allowed, there are areas above and below or to the right and left of the window that do not belong to the actual image.

How can scale and position the buttons depending on the current size of the image?

I tried to work with RelativeLayout, but the buttons seem to be oriented to the whole window, which I can't understand.
I also tried to work with ids, but I don't have the understanding to use it effectively.

Here some current code:

```py
class LaserApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
    Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
    Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'windowed')
    Config.write()
    LaserApp().run()
```

```
#:import ScrollEffect  kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button

Accordion:

    AccordionItem:
        title: 'titel1'
        collapse: False

    AccordionItem:    
        title: 'titel2'

    AccordionItem:
        title: 'relevant content'

        RelativeLayout:

            canvas:
            Image
                size_hint: 1, 1
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.texture_size
                source: 'background.png'

                canvas.after:
                RelativeLayout:

                    Button: #Button i want to align and resize depending on Image: / 'background.png'

    AccordionItem:
        title: 'titel4'
```

Any comments and help are very welcome.
Many Thanks in advance

P.S.: Please excuse the bad description.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem it sounds like you want something like this?:

```
_____________
|   |   |   |
_____________
|   |   |   |
_____________
|   |   |   |
_____________
```

You have to create multiple buttons with:

```
RelativeLayout:
    size_hint: 1,1
    pos: self.pos
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25 #rgba only, this makes the button semi-transparent
        pos_hint: {'x': .66, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25
        pos_hint: {'x': .33, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25
        pos_hint: {'x': .66, 'y': .33}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25
        pos_hint: {'x': .33, 'y': .33}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .33}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25
        pos_hint: {'x': .66, 'y': .66}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25
        pos_hint: {'x': .33, 'y': .66}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
    Button:
        background_color: 0,0,0,.25
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .66}
        size_hint: .33, .33
        on_release: print/function
```

As long as you have a Layout attached to your image with `size_hint: 1,1` and `pos: self.pos` this will bind the Layout to the same size and position of your image widget. The buttons in the example code should populate tiles that are 1/9 the size of the Layout as 9 are set in increments of .33 if you want more, just add more with the correct size_hint and pos_hint values. If RelativeLayout is an issue try using FloatLayout or BoxLayout, FloatLayout is similar to putting a blank canvas up and you can fill this widget anyway you see fit and BoxLayout functions by filling itself with children vertically or horizontally depending on how you set the `orientation:`. If this didnt fully answer your question or you need more help please let me know.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.
I had also tried a similar idea. I had positioned a button above and below the image to take the space beyond it.
Unfortunately such approaches don't work.
I think it's because of the way textures are processed.
While trying it out, I noticed that the image immediately takes over the parameters (height/width) of the background(window) and thus an alignment directly to the image is probably not possible.
I am grateful for further ideas